# How to check fields in DataGridView's new/added row

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

In a VB.NET project I'm building in VS2013 I need to check that the user entered values in certain fields when they add a record via the DGV's default new row at the bottom of the grid.

Do I access the values of the new row in the DGV, or is there a stored "table" that is created to hold the new data that I can access?

How do I do either of those to begin with?

Trying to find the value entered in the DGV, I know I can check if the row is new with:

```
dgvemployees.Rows(dgvEmployees.Rows.Count -1).IsNewRow
```

But when I enter a value in one of the cells and check it in the immediate window:

```
dgvemployees.Rows(dgvEmployees.Rows.Count -1).Cells(2).Value
```

I get "Nothing" (yes, I'm sure that's the correct column index).

Also, I know you can check the datarowstate of the datasource's table, which would require iterating through the whole set of changes (dataset.getchanges) as far as I know but I tried that but got an index out of range no matter what index I tried:

```
EmployeesDataSet.Tables("employees").Rows(dgvEmployees.Rows.Count - 1).RowState.ToString = DataRowState.Added.ToString
```

I guess I'm just not sure how to do this at all.

Comment: i overcame this problem by looping through each column to see if there was any data

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question, I'm getting "Nothing" for all of the column indexes.